# What does ''walk down the line'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I read the lyrics of Green Day's *Boulevard of Broken Dreams* and I found this:

> I'm walking down the line
>
> That divides me somewhere in my mind

What is the actual meaning of the first sentence?

Comment: The line (as is often the case with poetry) is intended to make you think about what is meant rather than telling you directly. You may infer that the singer is in some sense 'divided' in his mind and that he is trying to avoid choosing one 'side' and abandoning the other. Beyond that, it's up to you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for interpretation of a provocative metaphor.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why the metaphor is provocative, please?

Comment: Because it is intended to provoke thought or emotion rather than to express a proposition.

Comment: I understand more now. I will pay attention next time.

Comment: If it helps: to "walk a line" means to walk along a line, to follow a narrow path.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xObSJWIWui0

Comment: And here's him singing to guys who failed to "walk the line": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQWYc3_vE0I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a standard idiom, at least not one that I know of.

If you look at the next two or three lines, it sounds to me like he's saying that there is a dividing line in his mind, a border between two parts of his mind, and he's now walking along that line.

It's poetry, so the meaning is not strictly literal and may well be subject to interpretation.